# Underbrace under regular text, including spaces

Tags: formatting, text, underbrace

Solution:

```
 \newcommand{\undertext}[2] {\[\underbrace{\text{#1}}_{\text{#2}}\]}
```

Usage:

```
\undertext{textAbove}{textBelow}
```

I would simply like to use an underbrace under a regular, written sentence of text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous solutions. Perhaps easiest would be to simply use mathmode, wrapped inside a new command:

`\newcommand{\undertext}[2] {$\underbrace{\textrm{#1}}_{\textrm{#2}}$}`

Then you can simply `\undertext{do}{this}`.

Comment: Incredible solution! I am very impressed. Thank you. I have understood your command.

Comment: I really can't take credit for it, I'm certain it came from this forum … But glad it works for you.